# WCF Timeout when running on localhost in a VM

Tags: c#, wcf, virtualbox, performance

I am having an issue with running WCF service's locally. When I run the service's locally, it takes about 60+ seconds from the time the channel is opened on the client, until I see the method on the WCF service being called. If I connect to the services running on our staging environment, it works fine and there is no slowdown.

- I am running the client and Service on a new box running windows server 2008, inside a VM hosted by VirtualBox.
- IPV6 has been disabled on the VM
- I have a reference in my host file pointing towards localhost
- Verbose Logging on both the client and the host, only show exceptions being generated for timeouts on the client. Logging on the service shows no errors just a long time from start to finish of request.
- I turned off windows firewall with no effect.
- All of the config files for the client and service match the staging machines.

None of the other dev's where I work have this issue. I also do not have this issue on a separate box running windows7 (Not in a VM). Our staging servers are also all VM's (Server 2008) although they run on a different VM Platform.

Comment: How long does the Service method take if you don't run it through WCF? I.e. create a unit test & feed in the parameters from the client, but run entirely in-proc.

Comment: @Chris if I attach the debugger and run the method from start to end, it takes very little time, less than a second. Its only taking a long time form the client to the service and from the service to the client

Comment: Got it, just a couple more questions. How long does a ping take? is it only this specific call? do subsequent calls take less time?

Comment: @chris Ping takes less than 1ms. It seems to be all the calls to this service. Each call takes a long time. Also, and I am not sure I mentioned this in my post, but I can hit the wsdl in IE and it comes up immediately if the service is warmed up.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending very small requests and wait for each response, this looks like the [Nagle's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm) hitting you.  Test by [disabling it](http://www.windowsreference.com/windows-vista/how-to-disable-nagle-algorithm-in-windows-vista/) temporarily.

If you are starting to see this not with the first call to the service, but only after the first 10 or so, it could be a session leak.  That means, one is creating a new service client for each call and then forgets to close it.  After `ServiceThrottlingBehavior.MaxConcurrentSessions` is exhausted on the server, each subsequent session has to wait until a previous one times out and then it quickly succeeds.  Test by reducing `CloseTimeout` from its default of 60 seconds and see whether that is the timeout that governs what you see.  Then, of course, find the session leak and close it for a real fix.

If neither is your case, you can configure [service tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023.aspx) and use its output to enhance the question by more detail.

Comment: This is only a single request that is taking so long. Very little traffic is being sent

Comment: I have turned on tracing. Seeing no error messages, and nothing looks suspicious with the trace. When I get a chance I will submit a trace.